# Is it possible for a jQuery submit function to alter jQuery code elswhere or change which block is read?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table of venues, where each venue belong to an area and I'm attempting to learn abit about jQuery to use in my app. I have a filter form on the venue index page which filters venue partials by area. I also have a .png map image which shows all the areas and has icons placed by absolute positioning showing where the venues are in those areas.

The jQuery code in my index.html.erb changes the map image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("#area-1").is(':checked'))
        $(".map_container").addClass("area1");
      else if ($("#area-2").is(':checked'))
        $(".map_container").addClass("area2");
      else if ($("#area-3").is(':checked'))
        $(".map_container").addClass("area3");
      else
        nil;
    });
  });
</script>
```

The jQuery code in my venue partial displays the map icon:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px";
</script>
```

Is there a way to make the code in the index page which alters the map image also alter the code in the partial?

So if area1 is selected then the map image changes but also the code line in the partials which currently reads "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px" and "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px" reads "<%= venue.iconleftpx2 %>px" and "<%= venue.icontoppx2 %>px" instead? That way as the map image changes the location of the filtered venues icons change with it. Or is it possible to have 2 blocks of code and alter which is read depending on what is selected in the filter form?

Thanks for any help and sorry if my question is vaque or lacking, I'm super new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following you completely, but I think you could just load the map and the table at the same time and pull the coordinates for the map icons from the database with an ajax-get-request when the user submits.

On the server side, you can just add a JSON reply to for example the show action and have rails render the venue (or just the coordinates) to JSON.
Or you could have a special action that accepts an array of venue-id:s and returns an array of coordinates.

At the client-side, you would use the success or completion functions in the jQuery.ajax()-method to move the map icons using the JSON data you received.

[Information about jQuery ajax (jQuery API)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)